# How to import other files than `main` generated by webpack target in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am working on a javascript library which is built by `webpack`. The project will be built for two targets, `web` and `node`. I followed the instruction from this link: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/ to setup the multiple targets in webpack. It works fine and it generates two target files `build/test-web.js` and `build/test-node.js`.

The file `build/test-web.js` is listed in the main attribute in package.json as below:

```
"name": "@my-org/test
"main": "build/test-web.js",
```

so I am able to import this file by `require('@my-org/test')`. I wonder how I can import the other file `build/test-node.js`. I know I can import it via `require('@my-org/test/build/test-node.js')` but I am looking for a better solution to make developers import it more easily.

I checked this library: https://github.com/patrickhulce/generate-export-aliases but it doesn't work for `scoped package name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great [Setting up multi-platform npm packages](http://2ality.com/2017/04/setting-up-multi-platform-packages.html) article by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer which explains how you can achieve what you want.

Node.js will only look at the `main` field of `package.json` to resolve a module so you should put there the path to `build/test-node.j`. The builders which bundle browser code (i.e. Webpack, Rollup) will first additionally look at the `browser` field (if `target: web`) where you should specify the path to your `build/test-web.j`. So your package.json should look like this:

```
{
    ...
    "main": "build/test-node.j",
    "browser": "build/test-web.j",
    ...
}
```